# Remap CapsLock to Control-T

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm attempting to replicate ChromeOS's "Search" key in Ubuntu 11.04.

Mapping one key to a single other key works fine (xmodmap, etc.).  But I haven't been able to determine how to map one key, CapsLock to two keys, Ctrl-T.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards

Comment: @fossfreedom: I am interested in exactly this - the old xmodmap way no longer works in unity as of 14.04

Comment: @false suggest create your own question which you can edit and maintain